# localhost ajax error intermitent

Tags: .net, ajax, webforms

On my local host I have two pages

- form.aspx
- getandreturn.aspx

What normally happens is using ajax I post data from  `form.aspx` to `getandreturn.aspx` . when the post happens the debugger stops at the page_load at the break point so that I know that it is working.

This happens most of the time but sometimes and this is very random I get a 500 error and It wont hit the break point at all.

I am using jquery , .net 4 , web forms and the data posted is identicle

thanks